# uninitialized constant Dalli (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, memcached

i used ree to test dalli gem, but i got one error: uninitialized constant Dalli (NameError)

my test code is :

```
   require 'rubygems'
   require 'dalli'

   dc = Dalli::Client.new('192.168.1.10:11211')
   dc.set('abc', 123)
   value = dc.get('abc')
```

and i am sure i have installed dalli 1.1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason , my test file name is dalli.rb, so it can not require dalli gem